# What is this BNC-type radio connector about 13mm diameter?

Tags: antenna, connectors

What is this radio connector? LIKE BNC, but it is about 13mm in diameter, odd.

[image: VHF Connector]

Follow up:
It turns out putting a sma BNC adapter in the center of it does work.
In place of a "C" or "N" type to BNC, could I just use jbweld or some sturdy glue around this instead of holding it with the center tap in the center tap of the adapter?

Comment: If this is from some military surplus gear, you ought to show the whole thing, including any part numbers. There were all kinds of special connectors before efforts at standardization were made by different military.

Comment: @jdv exactly, see follow up

Answer (score 6):

That looks like a Type-C RF connector.

Pic from wikipedia  [image]

Comment: Funny, I knew that N connectors were created by the N of BNC, but I didn't know that C had his own too!

Comment: https://army-radios.groups.io/g/main/topic/harris_as_3588_vhf_uhf/74866426?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,74866426 It looks like they are 40 bucks or more - unavailable and higher priced on Digikey...

Comment: See followup - pushing an adapter into center works, so would it work to "JBWeld" it in place there?